# Android: how to grant 666 privs to a device via ueventd.rc

Tags: android, device, file-permissions, rooted-device

I need to access an USB camera connected to my (rooted) Android. I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2.2. I want to access it with a normal app, so I need the device to be world readable.

I can connect via shell and type

```
root@android:/ # su
root@android:/ # cd /dev
root@android:/dev # chmod 666 video4
```

and it works. But each time I disconnect the camera, and reconnect it, I have to do it again.

Via shell I can remount the root file system r/w

```
mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /
```

and then  edit the file `/ueventd.rc`  (actually it's  `/ueventd.qcom.rc` )

and add

```
/dev/video*               0666   system     camera
```

But even if I put 666 I only get

```
root@android:/dev # ls -la video4                                              
crw-rw---- system   camera    81,  18 2013-08-08 10:14 video4
```

Is there a way to grant a 666 permission permanently? So that each time I connect the camera it gets the right file permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After you replace the `/ueventd.qcom.rc` file, you must restart `/sbin/ueventd` service. Actually, it will restart automatically, you only need to find it `ps u`, and kill the **pid**.

Note that Samsung restores **rootfs** on every reboot. The way I handle it, I keep the changed copy of `ueventd.qcom.rc` in `/data/local/tmp`, and issue

```
su -c mount -o remount,rw /
su -c cp /data/local/tmp/ueventd.qcom.rc /
ps ueventd
```

>

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      198   1     1136   448   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/ueventd
```

`kill`**`198`**

Answer (score 0):

There are Triggers available in init.rc, device-add- and device-removed, it seems perhaps this could give you the opportunity to set the permissions:
https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/readme.txt#L126